# How can I get route values from inside my ActionExecuting filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I get route values from inside my `OnActionExecuting` filter method.

I had the following two suggestions but I am still confused:

1. Access your `ControllerContext` in the method and that gives you access to `RouteValues` so `filterContext.Controller.RouteValues`
2. Access `filterContext.Controller.RouteValues`

I have for example the method:

```
public ActionResult Delete(string city, string street) {
    //enter code here
}
```

If I want to get the value of city and street then how can I do this. Sorry if it seems like a basic question but I am not sure how to get access to the above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here it is,

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var parameters = filterContext.ActionParameters;
        var email = parameters["email"];
        var city = parameters["city"];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to preempt some controller action (like `Delete`) with "enter code here":

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    string city = filterContext.ActionParameters["city"];
    string street = filterContext.ActionParameters["street"];

    // probably include this:
    //base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```