# Strategies to prevent the user from accessing GET request of other ids

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I am currently brainstorming and researching right now about implement `sessions` for my ASP MVC application.

I already did the `Authentication` and `Authorization` part but now i have to fix this issue:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles="user")]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
        EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext();
        student st = emp.students.Single(x => x.id == id);    //get the student

        return View(st);
}
```

After the user successfully logged in, he will be directed to the details page by using a `GET` method.
My problem is that, the user can change the `id` and he will be able to view the other detail's page and i don't want that to happen. I want to make it possible that the only page that he can request is anything that has his `id`.

For my case: strictly `http://localhost:55319/Enrollment/Details/1` only and not `http://localhost:55319/Enrollment/Details/2`

Here is one of the solutions that i thought of but i don't feel that it's "scalable".

**Proposed solution:**
store the `id` in a session and use that to compare on the `id` that the user is currently trying to "`get`", but then again, i will have to type to them on every controller and i am trying to avoid that.

I read something about making a class that will inherit `ActionFilterAttribute` but the only usability that i know about it is "redirecting" if there is no current session.

Can anyone give me tips on how to implement it?

Comment: You need to validate if the user has access to the resource in the controller. Is the `id` the ID of the User? In which case it might be `if (currentUser.ID = id) { return the view } else { return an error }`

Comment: yes that's the ID. would that be alright though? because currently, i have 4 controllers that requires `id` for the `GET` and that would mean i have to type to all of them. I am wondering if there is a one shot solution.

Comment: If you need this multiple times, you can always create a action filter (implements `IActionFilter`) that performs the logic and apply it to the methods.

Comment: alright thanks. let me read on that one.

Comment: So i will store it in `Session` then retrieve it on my `ActionFilter` ?

Comment: Better to avoid session and access the User in the filter

Comment: You could perhaps make another method in the controller, `/Enrollment/MyDetails`, which doesn't take the user id from the URL but instead takes it from the current user...

Comment: @stephen, my problem right now is how do i store the current user id and pass/access it from the actionfilter.

Comment: You haven't indicated what sort of Authentication/Authorization you using so it hard to say, but you could store the ID in Session if you don't have access to it elsewhere

Comment: Ahh alright thank you. and last question, let's say i have this `http://localhost:55319/Enrollment/Details/1`, how do i access `1` from the `ActionFilter` ? ive been trying to search but i can't really word it out properly.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622482/how-can-i-get-route-values-from-inside-my-actionexecuting-filter) should help you out

Comment: Alright thank you so much :D

Comment: @Stephen alright, i fixed my problem and everything is working as expected. What i did was , since the id is already stored in `cache`, i will retrieve it and compare it with the `ActionParameter`. If both are not equal, i will just revert it to the original. Anyway thank you for the help.