# MVC redirecting on Null controller parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app that has 2 controllers.

Home and Details.

Details Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(long startTime, long endTime, string kpiName)
{
   // create my viewmodel.
   return View(detailsViewModel);
}
```

This page should only be called if the user clicks a details button on another page. The problem is the user can directly navigate to `http://localhost:54816/Details` and a YSOD is shown with the error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'startTime' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int64, Int64, System.String)' in 'SentlianKPI.Controllers.DetailsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

I tried adding a route as shown below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Details",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Details", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

With the idea being that the id is not optional so it will fail through to the Home controller.

It's not working though, how do I setup a route to catch this and redirect the user?

Comment: You can't stop a user entering a url in the address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the paramaters optional and then redirect them if they are null? The below code isn't tested.

```
  public ActionResult Index(long? startTime = null, long? endTime = null, string? kpiName = null)
    {
      if(startTime == null || endTime == null || kpiName == null){
        return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
       }
       // create my viewmodel.
       return View(detailsViewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the parameter to your controller method take a nullable int and then redirect from the controller method when the value is null? You could create a ReRouteIfNull filter attribute to decorate controller methods (and have it take a route parameter name and a redirect action) so that you don't have to add check and redirect logic to each controller method where you want this behavior (assuming you need it more than once).

Comment: Sounds nice. Could you provide a code snippet for it?

Comment: No, but here is an example of how to access route parameters from within  a filter which you could use for your redirect logic starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622482/how-can-i-get-route-values-from-inside-my-actionexecuting-filter